# How to add extra parameter to resources in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I want member routes generating by `resources` to contain additional parameter.

Something like:

```
resources :users
```

with folowing routes:

```
users/:id/:another_param
users/:id/:another_param/edit
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @tommyalvarez Added an answer to my own question.

Answer (score 20):

`resources` method doesn't allow you to do that. But you can do something similar using the `path` option and including extra parameters:

```
resources :users, path: "users/:another_param"
```

That will generate urls like this:

```
users/:another_param/:id
users/:another_param/:id/edit
```

In this case you will need to send `:another_param` value to routing helpers manually:

```
edit_user_path(@user, another_param: "another_value")
# => "/users/another_value/#{@user.id}/edit"
```

Passing `:another_param` value is not required if a default value has been set:

```
resources :users, path: "users/:another_param", defaults: {another_param: "default_value"}

edit_user_path(@user) # => "/users/default_value/#{@user.id}/edit"
```

Or you can even make the extra parameter not mandatory in the path:

```
resources :users, path: "users/(:another_param)"

edit_user_path(@user) # => "/users/#{@user.id}/edit"

edit_user_path(@user, another_param: "another_value")
# => "/users/another_value/#{@user.id}/edit"

# The same can be achieved by setting default value as empty string:
resources :users, path: "users/:another_param", defaults: {another_param: ""}
```

If you need extra parameters for particular actions, it can be done this way:

```
 resources :users, only: [:index, :new, :create]
 # adding extra parameter for member actions only
 resources :users, path: "users/:another_param/", only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Answer (score 3):

you could do something more explicit like

```
 get 'my_controller/my_action/:params_01/:params_02', :controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'
```

Comment: I necessarily need to use resources method

Answer (score 2):

```
resources :users, path: 'user' do
  collection do
    get ':id/:some_param', action: :action_name 
    get ':id/:some_param/edit', action: :custom_edit
  end
end
```

Comment: Adding routes manually like you did is not a problem. I need to avoid it. I necessarily need to use resources method only.

Comment: Patch actionpack then.

Comment: Why necessarily? Just curious, whats your usecase?